# Tracking Network Outages

Tags: networking, performance, firewall, troubleshooting, admin-tools

For the past couple of weeks, we've been experiencing poor network performance at the office. It is an intermittent issue. I work at a small office and we recently installed new antivirus software. We're behind a SonicWall NSA 3500 firewall with the content filter set for pornography and malware. I'm not sure what exactly is causing the poor network performance. Is there a tool I can use that will pinpoint the exact cause? Is wire-shark thorough in this type of instances?